# Regular Expression to match amounts

Tags: c++, regex, qt5

I have this regular expression:

```
^-?([0-9]{1,3})+([ 0-9]{3})*([\.0-9]{2})?$
```

Format should be marked as valid:

```
190 254 254
10 254 254
1 254 982
250 254
10 254
1 154
190 254 254.22
10 254 254.22
1 254 982.22
250 254.22
10 254.22
1 154.22
-190 254 254
-10 254 254
-1 254 982
-250 254
-10 254
-1 154
-190 254 254.22
-10 254 254.22
-1 254 982.22
-250 254.22
-10 254.22
-1 154.22
```

But after I tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lE5dD1/7) I got only partial matching.

**UPDATE:**
After correcting the regular expression by Mr @anubhava, the QLineEdit now accepts other formats too:

```
4654d654
55d54
444444
```

These is how I validate the input:

```
QRegExp rx("^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?: [0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$");
QValidator *currencyValidator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);
ui->unitPrice->setValidator(currencyValidator);
```

It turns out that I didn't escape the backslash:

```
QRegExp rx("^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?: [0-9]{3})*(?:\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$");
                                          ^
```

Comment: What is the strict definition of what should and what shouldn't match? An example of regexp that matched all of the examples: `^-?([0-9]{1,3})+( [0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by modifying your regex to this:

```
^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?: [0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Rather than keeping space and DOT inside the character class match them before the character classes.

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE5dD1/9)

Answer (score 1):

This segment `([0-9]{1,3})+` means:

```
(        Start of capturing group
  [0-9]    Match digit
  {1,3}    Match 1-3 of previous (digit)
)        End of capturing group
+        Match 1 or more of previous (capturing group)
```

The result is that it will match 1 or more digits, capturing the last 1-3 digits.

Since `{1,3}` is greedy, it prefers matching 3, so for input `12345678`, that means:

```
123   First repetition of capturing group
456   Second repetition of capturing group
78    Third repetition of capturing group
```

And since only the last repetition of the group is actually captured, you get `78`, which is not what you want. See [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tS7fX7/1) for more info.

That was just the first of three segments of your regex. All three segments are mixing `{n,m}` with `+` or `*`. `+` is just shorthand for `{1,}`, `*` is shorthand for `{0,}`, and `?` is shorthand for `{0,1}`.
So, `x{1,3}+` really means `x{1,3}{1,}`, and that makes no sense, so stop doubling the repetitions.

---

So, what should your regex be? Probably something like this:

```
(-?[0-9]{1,3})(?: ([0-9]{3}))? ([0-9]{3}(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)
```

For input `-190 254 254.22`, that will return `-190`, `254`, and `254.22`. See [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lY4wH7/1) for full test.